# Lock selected rows, so that other transactions ignore them on read

Tags: sql, database, multithreading, transactions, db2

this question is about optimization.
The scenario in question is as follows:

I have a table with data that should be read and acted upon by multiple transactions. The table consists of three columns: {id, message, status}.

```
ID   MESSAGE          STATUS
1    First Message    NEW 
2    Second Message   MOD
3    Third Message    FIN
....
```

As shown, the status is either one of these three states: {new, mod, fin}. They indicate if a row is new, is being processed at this moment or has been processed successfully.
I do this so that multiple transactions work on this table. A transaction reads all "NEW" Messages and change the status to "MOD", to indicate that they are being processed and to lock them. After that they are processed. Successfully processed rows will be set to "FIN" and failed ones to "NEW" so that the next transaction will try those again.

Other than the changing of the status, the table is readonly. The accual information that is to be processed is never altered.

The process described above works, but I think its unnecessarily complicated. What I look for here is a simpler solution. I've already read about different isolation levels but they all basically cause the rows to be lock in a way so that other transactions have to wait. I dont want that. Instead I would like those already read rows to be ignored by the other queries.

Now finally, on to the question:
Is it possible to lock rows on read, so that they will be ignored by other transations, instead of the transactions waiting for those rows to be unlocked?

I want something like this:
Lets say the table holds 30 rows.

- Transaction "reader1" reads 30 rows, (id 1-30). These rows are now locked (preferably invisible for everybody else).
- Transaction "writer" inserts 20 new rows. (id 31-50)
- At this point, "reader1" is not finished yet. Without having to wait for "reader1" to finish, transaction "reader2" reads only the new 20 rows, because the other rows (1-30) are hidden by "reader1"
- "reader1" and "reader2" finish. It does not matter in which order they finish, since they work on disjunct datasets.

Is there a way to do this without the need of a status column?

---

- DBMS used is DB2 by IBM
- Access via ODBC

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Why should rows read by one user be invisible to other users?

Comment: It will likely depend on what DBMS you're using, and how it handles lock contentions (there are various strategies, such as dirty read, last clean read, etc) which can often be configured. However this is outside Relational Theory, and even the SQL standard, and will be implementation specific.

Comment: @jarlh I added some info. I want to do this so that every row is only processed once and so that I dont have to hadle my status the indicate which row is being processed at that moment. I want to minimize writing and reading.

Comment: @Rags as added to the question, DBMS is DB2

Comment: Add the *platform* of the Db2-server (Z/os, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows) and the *version* of Db2-server sofware.

Comment: Why? How much of a standard do you want to use?

Comment: Side note: potentially the current implementation _doesn't_ work, depending on what other tracking you're (not) doing.  For example, what happens if a processor flips the row to `'MOD'`, and then crashes?  Presumably they **stay** in that status.  It also requires you to hold the entire set in memory, since (unless you have some sort of batch/processor number) you couldn't re-query for all the `'MOD'` rows

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this without the need of a status column?

In short, no, but not due to locking/parallelism concerns.

In reality, you need that status column simply so that, when your processing system eventually goes down, you know what rows you need to process again when it comes back up.  That it actually makes it easier to do work in parallel is a side benefit.

As for the rest of your question:

> I've already read about different isolation levels but they all basically cause the rows to be lock in a way so that other transactions have to wait. I dont want that. Instead I would like those already read rows to be ignored by the other queries.

...well, you're in luck, cause that's not what you want to happen anyways.  Your primary problem is that in order to lock rows with *only* a read, you not only have to prevent other processes from reading those rows (since read-only locks are normally shared), you have to prevent rows from being **inserted** as well.  If instead, however, you lock a row with a **write**, it becomes vastly simpler and easier to interleave processes.

And all you need is [`Cursor Stability`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html#c0004121__cs):

> However, if any data in the row was changed, the lock is held until the change is committed.
>
> Under this isolation level, no other application can update or delete a row while an updatable cursor is positioned on that row. Under CS, access to the uncommitted data of other applications is not possible. *However, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads are possible.*

...allowing other processors to update similar data is what non-repeatable reads are about.  We actually want them to occur!  We don't want phantom reads (which is what would happen if two rows read the same data and then tried to update it), but we can design our application around that.

One way to do this is to start your unit of work (this might be implicit or explicit, depending on the platform), and then issue an update statement:

```
UPDATE Transactions SET status = 'MOD'
WHERE status = 'NEW'
```

Then just retrieve your updated rows so you know what to process:

```
SELECT id, message
FROM Transactions
WHERE status = 'MOD'
```

Mark them as finished:

```
UPDATE Transaction SET status = 'FIN'
WHERE status = 'MOD'
```

And finally commit the changes:

```
COMMIT
```

(note that this version has a slight weakness - if the system goes down after updating to `'FIN'` but before the commit, the row will be reset to `'NEW'`, which might be its own problem.  But at least `'MOD'` would be rolled back correctly)